# Extjs Rendering value using id

Tags: javascript, extjs, dynamic, reference, frameworks

I am trying to get the value by id

```
 window.setInterval(function () {
                me.updateData({
                    Name: "aaa, aaa",
                    Id: "1234",
                    Vitals: [{
                        Name: "value1",
                        Timestamp: new Date(),
                        Value: getRandomInt(60, 80) + "/" + getRandomInt(60, 80)
                    }, {
                        Name: "value2",
                        Timestamp: new Date(),
                        Value: getRandomInt(60, 80)
                    }, {
                        Name: "value3",
                        Timestamp: new Date(),
                        Value: getRandomInt(60, 80)
                    }, {
                        Name: "value4",
                        Timestamp: new Date(),
                        Value: getRandomInt(60, 80)
                    }
                    ]
                });              
            }, 1000);

items: [{
            id:'value'
                   ,tpl: 
                        '<div class="col-md-3 red ">{Value}</div>' 
                }
```

above scenario working fine.
But i need to use it by dynamically generated div like

```
items: [{
                   tpl: 
                        '<div id="value" class="col-md-3 red ">{Value}</div>'                 
                }
```

But the value in not binding in {Value} 
Thank You

Comment: Can you post the whole code in order to have a better understanding of what you are trying to do? Maybe in a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'dataview',
        itemId: 'ItemId',
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '<div class="col-md-3 red ">',
                    '<h3>{value}</h3>',
                '</div>',
            '</tpl>'
        ),
        itemSelector: 'col-md-3 red',
        prepareData: function(data, index, record) {
             var name = this.up().getViewModel().get('value');
             var passed = record.get('value') == name;
             return Ext.apply(data);
        }           
     }
```